# Multiple VR in one mobile app

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I am developing an app with google cardboard VR sdk in Unity. I have succesfully deployed it as an apk ( on my mobile under developer mode ).

Now, I would like to know if there's a way of seeing multiple VR games in one app. For example, I have a search bar in my Android app that filters games, and once it filters I need to retrieve various games that will be hosted in my server ( instead of having one apk per game ).

Comment: Do you have source code of these other games? If not I can't see how it will work. Probably you will be able to open these other apps, if they are installed, but this solution will move you towards other UX problems.

Comment: Yes, all games are mine

Comment: Therefore, you could create a main scene where people could choose in a menu, then you load the main scene of the chosen game.

Comment: That is an option but it isn't scalable, because everytime I upload a game, the user will have to update the apk. I wondered if there's any way to load those new scenes ( or games ) from the main apk, without having neither to update the main apk nor downloading apks for each game. An option that I was considering was some sort of web container that loads data and the scenes from my server ( something like a scenes-database), but I don't know if that's possible.

Comment: Inside Android's world there is a concept of ipk, maybe you could try to search about it and how to implement it in Unity.